# Culture paramaters in URL as route

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to modify the .htaccess file to allow URL's to specify region and language information as a route and transform the request into a query string parameter.

**Exmple**
domain/us/en -> domain/index.html?reg=en&lan=us
domain/ca/fr -> domain/index.html?reg=ca&lan=fr

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /index.html?reg=$2&lan=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! That seemed to work great, just need to update image and resource links to start with '/' from root.

Comment: You're welcome, yes better to use absolute links for css/js/images for pretty links.

Comment: Any idea on how I would be able to access these URL parameters from within a PHP file? I changes the 'index.html' file to a php script, how would I go about grabbing the url parameters? Thanks again for you help!

Comment: Just use `$_GET` array.

Comment: Thanks again, just found an article online saying the same thing. Thanks for all your help!